# SQL Server 2008 - sum of a column where column name is a parameter in SP

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm fairly new to stored procedures and I think this may need just a simple syntax adjustment but here we go.

I have a stored procedure with 2 parameters, a column name and ID. all I need to do is divide each value by a number, sum all the values in the column given where the ID = the ID given and return the sum.

In a non-SP form this seemed to work:

```
select isnull(sum(Column_Name/3600),0) from My_Table where ID = 12345678
```

However I tried to create this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Col_Sum @Column_Name varchar(100), @ID char(8)

AS
BEGIN
SELECT isnull(sum(@Column_Name/3600,0) 
FROM My_Table 
WHERE ID = @ID

RETURN
END
```

The query attempts to treat @Column_Name as an integer and fails to complete. How do I get the procedure to take @Column_Name similar to my original working query? Or is there a better alternative? Thanks.

Comment: If your column name is being passed in as a parameter (meaning it will change when you run this), then you will need to use dynamic sql.

Comment: More like this? :    `CREATE PROCEDURE Col_Sum @Col_Name varchar(25), @ID char(8)

AS
BEGIN
SET @SQL_Command = 'SELECT isnull(sum(' + @Column_Name + '/3600),0) 
FROM My_Table
WHERE ID = ' + @ID

EXEC(@SQL_Command)
END`